# Resolve warning of expiration of certificate while creating release apk using cordova cli

Tags: java, cordova, certificate

I have created a keystore with the command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore <KeystoreName.keystore> -alias <aliasname> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Where I have set validity with 10000, once I have created release apk with this, which works fine but after 3 months now i wanted to create new version of it and it is showing me a warning

> Warning:
>   No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2043-07-12) or after any future revocation date.

And cannot generating new release apk, Now please let me know how do i skip this warning and create a updated release apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this is to add

```
//Certificate for -tsa into jarsigner command 
-tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com 

jarsigner -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <keystorename> <apkname.apk> <aliasname>
```

And my problem is solved !!!
May be this will help others too ! So I am answering my own question here.
Thanks